# Is there any way to simplify Cos( 2/3 ArcTan(x) )?

Tags: trigonometry

Does a trigonometric identity exist that resolves

$$\cos\left( \frac{2}{3} \arctan(x) \right)$$

into something that does not involve any trigonometric functions?
Note that avoiding trigonometric functions also means avoiding the appearance of imaginary units $i$, since these are just sines and cosines in disguise. Assume $x$ is such that the above function is real.

Comment: fractional... as in a rational number?

Comment: fractional as in rational function in $x$ or involving radicals (square or higher roots). basically, the aim is to get rid of trigonometric functions if possible, I will edit the question to make what I mean crearer.

Comment: i would tend to say no... because the output of arctan is an arbitrary angle, so essentially your input to cos() has no limitation or pattern and can be any angle, therefore cos() itself will remain as it is, a transcendental function. i could be wrong but....

Comment: Whatever the closed form might be, the graph is pretty. http://i.imgur.com/FUuNEA6.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\cos\left(\frac{2}{3}\arctan(x)\right)=\cos^2\left(\frac{1}{3}\arctan(x)\right)-\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{3}\arctan(x)\right)\end{align}$$
Then by the triple angle formula for cosine,
$\cos{\theta}=4\cos^3\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)-3\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$
Here we must solve for $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$, something which is not trivial; it is a cubic equation. But there will be a closed form for the roots, and you can then substitute that back into the above formula, with $\theta=\arctan(x)$. Do the same for sine's triple angle formula*: $\sin{\theta}=3\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)-4\sin^3\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$. Then it's trivial since $\cos(\arctan(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and $\sin(\arctan(x))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. So there definitely is a way to do it, but the amount of effort required would be enormous.

*Looks like someone already has, which makes it signifantly less work: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-formula-for-sin-x-3-one-third-angle-formula
$$\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-\sin(\theta)\pm\sqrt{\sin^2(\theta)-1}}{8}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{-\sin(\theta)\mp\sqrt{\sin^2(\theta)-1}}{8}}$$

Comment: I wonder what these plus minus signs are all about. Is the sign selection on the RHS only valid for some restricted angle region respectively?

Comment: Oh, no, never mind. The solution is symmetric under simultaneous exchange of the signs in both terms.